# Fusion table api query

Tags: count, google-fusion-tables

With reference to [this link](http://michelleminkoff.com/2012/02/05/how-to-count-queried-rows-in-a-google-fusion-table/), when I added the code to my sample map to count the markers it works. The code is,

```
var tableid="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var queryUrlHead = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=?';
var query = "SELECT COUNT() FROM tableid"
var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);
var getCount = $.get(queryurl,
function(data){
try{
$('#count').html((data.table.rows[0][0]));
}
catch(err){
$('#count').html('0');
}
},
"jsonp");
```

But when I changed my api to v1 as

```
   var tableid="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
   var apiKey = "XXXXXXXX";
   var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
   var queryUrlTail = '&key=' + apiKey + '&callback=?';
  var query = "SELECT COUNT() FROM tableid"
var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);
var getCount = $.get(queryurl,
function(data){
try{
$('#count').html((data.table.rows[0][0]));
}
catch(err){
$('#count').html('0');
}
},
"jsonp");
```

**EDIT:** My sample map with [old api code](http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/3/) and [new api code](http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/4/) is here respectively. The new API shows zero count. How can I fix it?

Comment: My [sample map is here](http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/3/).

Comment: I see 24 in your [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/S2WMf/3/)

Comment: Yes.. It is in old api. I commented new api v1. Please uncomment it and comment the old api codes `var queryUrlHead = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=?';` and run. It gives zero

Comment: Maybe you should: 1. make that clear. 2. post both versions (since you are the one asking for help), they should also be added to your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you need to change this line:

```
$('#count').html((data.table.rows[0][0]));
```

to this:

```
$('#count').html((data.rows[0][0]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4D7DV/1/